# Make python requests and BeautifulSoup faster

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

Hi I want to get some data from a website (users and user's data) and them save data in a **SQLite** database.

- I want to make this processes more faster
- and witch is better comet data for every filed or comet data after finishing scraping.

I use **lxml** and **cchardet**. But that's not make efficient change.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce time in the scraping part, I suggest build a  multithreaded program to make requests. `concurrent.futures` is one of the easiest ways to multithread these kinds of requests, in particular using the [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor). They even have a simple multithreaded URL request example in the documentation.

```
import concurrent.futures as futures
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

urllist = ...

def get_url_data(url, session):
    try:
        r = session.get(url, timeout=10)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError:
        return None

    return r.text

s = requests.Session()

try:
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as ex:
        future_to_url = {ex.submit(get_url_data, url, s): url
                         for url in urlist}

    results = {future_to_url[future]: future.result() 
               for future in futures.as_completed(future_to_url)}
finally:
    s.close()
```

Also, you may want to check out python [scrapy framework](https://scrapy.org/), it will scrape the data concurrently, also it comes with many features such as auto-throttle, rotating proxies and user-agents, you can easily integrate with your databases as well.